# "Thus" at the beginning of the sentence or between subject and verb

Tags: word-order

"Thus" can be used both at the very beginning of the sentence, or between the subject and the verb:

> At high altitude, the boiling point of water is lower than at sea-level.
>
> 1. Thus, pasta takes a longer time to cook.
> 2. Pasta thus takes a longer time to cook.

Are there differences between them?

Comment: No, except _thus_ is a higher register  word usually used in sentences with more weight than talking about cooking times for pasta. _So pasta takes longer to cook._

Comment: @KarlG "more weight than [...] pasta". Please don't say this in front of an angry Italian.

Comment: @KarlG jokes aside, it's a simple example that illustrates my question well enough.